# go wire, wiring up the dependencies

Tags: go, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am using [Google wire](https://github.com/google/wire) to wire up the dependencies in one of my Go projects. So far all the dependencies were wired up successfully.

I have following container:

```
type Container struct {
    Logger               logger.StructuredLogger
    IDGenerator          idgenerator.IDGenerator
    Arango               arangodb.Arango
}
```

Here `StructuredLogger`, `IDGenerator` and `Arango` are interface.

The container set is defined as below:

```
var mockContainerSet = wire.NewSet(
    Container{},
    ResolveStructuredLogger,
    ResolveIDGenerator,
    ResolveArangoDB,
)
```

Functions:

```
func ResolveStructuredLogger() logger.StructuredLogger {
    panic(wire.Build(wire.InterfaceValue(new(logger.StructuredLogger), logrusprovider.NewLogrusLogger(nil))))
}

func ResolveIDGenerator() idgenerator.IDGenerator {
    panic(wire.Build(wire.InterfaceValue(new(idgenerator.IDGenerator), examples.NewKSUIDGenerator())))
}
```

Now the issue is when I want to create a provider for `Arango`. The factory method for `Arango` provider is taking `IDGenerator` as an argument.

```
func NewMockedArango(generator idgenerator.IDGenerator) (*MockedArango, error){
    if generator == nil {
        return nil , errors.New("mock arangodb expects a valid IDGenerator")
    }
    return &MockedArango{generator:generator}, nil
}
```

All the functions from `arangodb.Arango` is implemented. And I tried the following to create a provider:

```
func ResolveMockArangoDB(idGenerator idgenerator.IDGenerator) (arangodb.Arango, error) {
    panic(wire.Build(wire.InterfaceValue(new(arangodb.Arango), mockdb.NewMockedArango(idGenerator))))
}
```

But the wire is throwing errors, I tried a lot of ways and no success to set this up. Any help?

Error:

> 2-valued mockdb.NewMockedArango(idGenerator) (value of type
>   (*github.com/tejashwi/catalog-manager-svc/pkg/webservice/arangodb/mockdb.MockedArango,
>   error)) where single value is expected

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: @Gerep updated the post, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Signature of wire.Interface is
`InterfaceValue(typ interface{}, x interface{})`

Here you need to pass two single-valued arguments. In the second argument, you are passing 2-valued argument since function `mockdb.NewMockedArango` is returning 2 values.

You can change function ResolveMockArangoDB to:

```
func ResolveMockArangoDB(idGenerator idgenerator.IDGenerator) (arangodb.Arango, error) {
    mockedArango, err := mockdb.NewMockedArango(idGenerator)
    <HANDLE err>
    panic(wire.Build(wire.InterfaceValue(new(arangodb.Arango), mockedArango)))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I need to return back both the instance and error. If I try with your code, I am getting the error `call to wire.Build indicates that this function is an injector, but injectors must consist of only the wire.Build call and an optional return`

Comment: My bad, I checked wire package, it does not allow expressions other than wire.build. I do not see any way to add error with wire.InterfaceValue. You need to pass just the instance of mockedArango